# How to set jSpinner value using existing data

Tags: java, netbeans, jspinner

I have an `ArrayList<Integer>` and I want to use two `jspinners`, one for getting the index of the `ArrayList` and the other for displaying the corresponding integer.

Comment: Why use a spinner for the corresponging element from the list? It seems a JLabel would be a better choice. Also, too broad.

Comment: it is compulsory that I use a spinner.

Comment: Do you need that changing the value on the second spinner will change the index on the first spinner, or only that changing the index on the first spinner will change the value on the second spinner?

Comment: Only changing the index on the first spinner will change the value on the second spinner!

Answer (score 1):

First limit the range of the first spinner to the size of the list prevent index-out-of-bounds exceptions:

```
jspinner1.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, yourList.size() - 1, 1));
```

Then add the event handler that will set the second spinner when the first one is changed. On Java 8+:

```
jspinner1.addChangeListener((ChangeEvent e) -> {
    jspinner2.setValue(yourList.get((int)jspinner1.getValue()));
});
```

On old versions of Java:

```
jspinner1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        jspinner2.setValue(yourList.get((int)jspinner1.getValue()));
    }
});
```